# $(window).bind('hashchange', function () is not working in my IE9

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My website use `$(window).bind('hashchange', function ())` to check if redirect is required. However, my site works fine in firefox not in IE9

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function ()
    {
        alert('hash change2');
        hash();
    });

$(window).load(function()
{

// Make sure cookies are enabled
$.cookie(global_cookie_prefix+'_cookies_test', '1');
var test_cookies_cookie = $.cookie(global_cookie_prefix+'_cookies_test');

if(test_cookies_cookie == null)
{
    window.location.replace('error.php?error_code=3');
}
else
{

    $.cookie(global_cookie_prefix+'_cookies_test', null);

    hash();
    /*
    alert('after hash0');

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function ()
    {
        //alert('hash change');
        //alert('hash change1');
        hash();
    });
    */
}
});
```

Everytime I need to refresh the entire page to make the page redirect successfully.

Please, any idea?

/*! jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */

Comment: What JQuery version are you using? The 2.x versions do not support IE9 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find the solution. Added one line at doctype html then everything work fine

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
```